# Is there a format to write a good treasure hunt story?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, plot, structure, genre

I'm writing a story for an Indian movie that revolves around a bunch of estranged siblings, who come to live in their father's abandoned house a year after his death. They do so because they receive knowledge that there is a huge treasure hidden in that house. I want to understand the best way to structure the story. If there is a format that could be followed, it would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no characteristic structure for treasure-hunt stories. For example, it wouldn't help you to read the quintessential example *Treasure Island*, because the fact about that novel that most impacts its structure is not the presence of a treasure hunt, but its being a coming of age story for Jim Hawkins.

The best stories, whether they involve treasure-hunting or otherwise, have fantastic character development. What will happen to your characters? Will they move past whatever estranged them despite the family connection? Or will initially minor disagreements eventually become something very dark out of competition for the treasure? That's up to you, and you might do a combination of these ideas or something else. But if you want to plan your story and its structure, you might find it best to work backwards from such decisions to the plot itself.

Let's say the siblings look around the house, find something confusing, realise its implications for how they could find the treasure, keep following the threads, eventually get it and decide how it should be shared and used. They'll learn a lot about the house, and probably family members, along the way; and the things they learn are far more important to character development than the $$$.

How was the treasure accrued; were the means honest, and were they what everyone thought going in? Is the treasure itself what people thought it was? Why was it hidden there, and why did no-one get it yet? Do all the siblings know, or think, the same things going in? If their knowledge differs, does it create conspiracy against others or the suspicion of it? How does the geography of the house help subsets of the group talk behind others' backs?

I'll leave it with you.

Comment: Could Heist Stories, which do have a characteristic structure, be a form of Treasure-Hunt?

Comment: @EDL Heists have a battle-of-wits/cat-and-mouse element to steal something owned and guarded, which has led to many tropes characterizing a genre. But good advice on how to write heists is tangential to how to write a good story in which a treasure is hunted but isn't heisted in the above sense.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was imagining the obligatory collecting of tools and people in the heist story share something with the collecting of clues in a Treasure hunt.

Answer (score 1):

*General Plot*

```
plot = characters + problem + plot twist + conclusion
```

*Treasure Hunt Plot*

For treasure hunt stories you would swap the problem with the prize:

```
plot = characters + treasure + plot twist + conclusion
```

*Example*

A young cabin boy travels with his ship to an island rumored to hold a buried treasure, but the hunt for the treasure is postponed due to a betrayal by half the crew. With the captain by his side the boy becomes a man and finds the treasure.

*Another One*

A boy leaves home to find the greatest treasure on earth. Along the way he meets good friends and recruits the best of the best to join him. When he reaches the place the treasure was supposed to be, he realizes the real treasure was the people he met along the way.